# application of article "the"

Tags: sentence-construction, definite-article

which sentence is correct regarding the use of article "the":

> There was a significant difference between the pretest and the post-test values of the students’ depression.

or

> There was a significant difference between the pretest and post-test values of the students’ depression

Comment: I think in this case there is no difference.

Comment: Both versions are perfectly valid, but in this exact context it's probably more common to omit the article before ***post-test***. Note that it would be perfectly okay to omit the article before ***pre-test*** (provided the other one was *also* discarded), and arguably that might be the *most* likely choice for competent writers).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can we omit both if there is the singular "value"?

Comment: @Cardinal: It would be slightly unusual to use singular "value" in your context. You say there's a pre-test value *and* a post-test one, so by definition there are two "values" (I assume they're numerical assessment values indicating "incidence / severity of depression"). For reasons that aren't clear to me I find it "less unusual" if we shift the context so "value" means "[monetary] worth", as in *difference between the pre-Brexit and post-Brexit value of the pound relative to the dollar*. And for reasons unknown, I wouldn't omit the first article if I *did* use the singular (unlikely).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for the gggreat explanation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the tendency to use the plural or the singular will depend on the meaning we assign to "value". As you say, where it means "worth", it will remain in the singular (we never speak about the "values of the pound"). However, if it means "rates" as in the question, it will most likely take the plural form.

Comment: I’d leave out the second “the”. It’s not incorrect, it’s just not necessary. The first “the” also covers the second object so it’s nice to have the shorter sentence. Leaving this as a comment because I’m not sure of the technicalities of this, it’s just how I would write it.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. In a list, you can repeat, or not, the modifiers. It works a bit like math:

> the (pretest + post-test) == the pretest + the post-test

Here's another example with adjectives

> blue (monkeys and spiders) == blue monkeys and blue spiders

While there is a semantic equivalence, you do run the risk of someone misunderstanding:

> (blue monkeys) and spiders

Which is why you'll often see the modifier repeated

> blue monkeys and blue spiders

Of course, if you intend to apply the modifier only to one, then switch the order so there's no chance of misunderstanding

> spiders and blue monkeys

Comment: -1 because OP isn't asking about *adjective noun1 **and** noun2* contexts where it's potentially ***ambiguous*** whether the adjective also applies to *noun2*. He's asking about repetition of an *article*, in contexts where it's meaningless to think in terms of resolving ambiguity, since there can be none.

Comment: Okay @FumbleFingers, then just read the first two lines. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, G. Ann's answer was informative (it answered the question) and clarified the scope of the rule (it's the same single rule, after all), which is quite clearly relevant. There's nothing wrong with fully explaining a concept, and it may in fact help more than treating repetitive article omission as an isolated case (after all, adjectives are easier to understand conceptually).